# DOMPDF + Codeigniter, library upgraded, but now not working

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I have been using the old version of dom pdf in codeigniter for pdf generation and recently I changed the core dompdf directory to newer version dompdf-0.5.2.zip. 
Below is the code that I've been using to connect to dompdf class:

```
class Pdf{

var $_dompdf = NULL;

/**
 * Constructor Method
**/
function __construct(){
    ini_set("memory_limit", "1G");
    require_once("Dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    if(is_null($this->_dompdf)){
        $this->_dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    }
}

/**
 * HTML to PDF Conversion method
**/
function convert_html_to_pdf($_html, $_filename = '', $_stream = false, $_orientation = "portrait"){
    $this->_dompdf->set_paper("a4", $_orientation);
    $this->_dompdf->load_html($_html);
    $this->_dompdf->render();
    if($_stream){
        $this->_dompdf->stream($_filename);
    } else{
        file_put_contents($_filename, $this->_dompdf->output()); 
    }
}
```

}

Now when I try to generate pdf, it gives me following error:
Fatal error: Class 'DOMPDF' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\app\application\libraries\Pdf.php on line 21

any solution would be appreciated

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself by uploading the dompdf version to the latest version, though it is beta, all seems to work perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Please first try with this example. Just store this in a file under htdocs directory of your xampp or whatever server you are using.

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html =
 '<html><body>'.
 '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
 'templating system.</p>'.
 '</body></html>';

 $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
 $dompdf->load_html($html);
 $dompdf->render();
 $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");

?>
```

Just change the dompdf directory path as per your requirement.

Comment: I've solved this by upgrading my current version to the latest one.